# MySQL slow left join on sort

Tags: mysql, sql

I have millions of customers and when I use left join and then I sort by a column it takes 4-5sec here is my query:

```
SELECT c.id AS id, o.description AS office_description, ... , d.type AS document_type, d.number AS document_number
FROM customers c INNER JOIN offices o ON (c.id_office = o.id)
                 INNER JOIN company cp ON (o.id_company = cp.id)
                 LEFT JOIN documents d ON (C.id = d.id_customer)
WHERE c.archive = 0
ORDER BY office_description
LIMIT 10
```

So when I remove documents columns in my SELECT the query is very fast.

Here is the query explain :
[image]

I have 1 millions customers and other tables I have only 1 row (for company / office / documents)

I set index on c.archive / o.description and primary keys / foreigns keys ofc. Here is the structures of these tables: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a222f9

So I tried to build my query like this:

```
SELECT A.*, d.* 
FROM (
  SELECT c.id AS id, o.description AS office_description, ...
  FROM customers c INNER JOIN offices o ON (c.id_office = o.id)
                   INNER JOIN company cp ON (o.id_company = cp.id)
  WHERE c.archive = 0
  ORDER BY o.description
  LIMIT 10
) A LEFT JOIN documents d ON (A.id = d.id_customer)
```

And now, wow, it's very fast.

But I don't know if it's the best way to reduce the lag and if I'm doing wrong. I'd like to know if you know a better way to do that.

I hope there is an easier way because it will be complicated to use this query in my Phalcon project

Comment: The queries do different things.  You should. use the query that does what you really need.  As for performance, your question needs more information about the tables (sizes, indexes) and more information about the query (execution plan) for any reasonable answer.

Comment: Please share more details, like the table structure such that others can see how the indices are defined

Comment: Remove `Limit 10` and test again.

Comment: What's the `EXPLAIN` _without_ `documents`?

Comment: please add some index on your documents and offices tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An explanation...

Your faster query can find the 10 rows *before* looking in `documents`.  So, it needs only 10 probes into that table.

In the original query, the Optimizer was not too smart.  It planned to execute the query as if there were no `LIMIT`.  Instead, it decided to optimizer the join to `documents` by fetching the entire table into the "join buffer" into RAM and built a hash index into it.  While this would help some queries like yours, it was a big waste for the mere 10 rows that you needed.

So, your reformulation convinced the Optimizer to do it a better way.

If you had needed only one column from `d`, there is another way:

```
SELECT ...,
       ( SELECT col FROM d WHERE ... ) AS col,
    ... ((without the LEFT JOIN at all))
```

As for an "easier" way, especially one that can be reverse-engineered into some 3rd package, I doubt it.  (Packages tend to be cruxes for getting started in databases.  As you are finding out, you eventually need to learn more than they can teach you.)

A separate inefficiency:

```
WHERE c.archive = 0
ORDER BY o.office_description
LIMIT ...
```

If the archived rows had been removed from `c`, then the optimal execution would be to find the first 10 rows of `o`.  Instead it must do a lengthy `JOIN` before sorting and limiting.  (This is a common problem with "soft deletes".  Neither MySQL nor the 3rd party package can optimize it.)

Comment: Ok thank you for clarification so both queries will return the same result, I can keep the 2nd query ?

Comment: @John - Yes, the second query should give the same results, but faster.